# symfony2 Bundle Updater

Tags: symfony, bundle, auto-update, composer-php

I have a Sf2 project that I would like to distribute. The project is already usable but should/will be modified as time pass so I am looking for a solution, without reinventing the wheel, to implement an update function inside my application so that people get notified when an update is available and with a one-click procedure can upgrade their deployed version to the newest one.

Do you have any ideas? Is there something similar already around that i can take a look at?

Comment: It seems that, you should simply use Composer for that puropuse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Register here:

https://packagist.org/

and Use composer!

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit late. Ok, but I'd like to be able to update the project through web interface (not only command line).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Adam's answer, also don't forget to register your bundle at [knpbundles.com](http://knpbundles.com/)